# Perl - Writing Network content as a text file

Tags: perl

I believe this is basic, but I'm not getting how to do it. I'm transferring a file over network socket from one machine to another. I'm receiving the file contents as a network packet, on the receive side, i store the contents in a list variable. The contents are in hex format, its the payload from the network packet.

I now need to create a new perl text file and write these contents back as a text file. Any ideas?

```
my @str;
@str = $msg->{packet_contents};

open FILE, ">file.txt" or die $!; 
foreach (@str)
print FILE $_
```

The above lines of code is just dumping the Array Index .

I changed it to print using Dumper and that also did not help

```
open FILE, ">file.txt" or die $!; 
print FILE Dumper($msg->{packet_contents});
```

The above lines are printing something like below; But i need the text contents not the hex.

```
$VAR1 = [
          77,
          97,
          121,
          32,
          32,
          49,
```

I understand i cannot use Dumper, but how do i write the network socket contents as text file? Any pointers should suffice, don't need full implementation.

To Summarize:
 1. I have the file contents that are received over the network saved as a list.
 2. I need to open a text file.
 3. Write the list contents as a text file.

Comment: You might want to modernise [your code](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2011/04/13/perl-worst-practices/#two-argument-open) a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the values through the [`chr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) function to get the text:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @str = (77, 97, 121, 32, 32, 49);

print map {chr $_} @str;
```

Outputs:

```
May  1
```